# how do I override the default port of 3000 for NodeJS within an Electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an Electron app that uses an Angular frontend served at port 4201 and a NodeJS backend.  I want to make the app work multi-instance, which would require changing ports (I'm not sure yet whether to do this randomly or some other way).  While it's easy to change the frontend from one port to another, the NodeJS backend remains at port 3000 no matter what I do. What, if anything can I do to move it?  In Main.js I've tried

```
...
var routes = require('./backend_routes/query'); //importing route
routes(backend); //register the route
backend.listen(3001);
var win, serve;
var args = process.argv.slice(1);
serve = args.some(function (val) { return val === '--serve'; });
...
```

and the backend just keeps listening at port 3000.

EDIT:

There was a question about the code in backend_routes/query .
This is that code:

```js
//all the backend routes are specified here
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
    var query = require('../backend_controllers/query');
    var reports = require('../backend_controllers/reports');
    //Routes
    app.route('/query').get(query.execute);
    app.route('/databaselist').get(query.databaselist);
    app.route('/redodatabaseconnection').get(query.redodatabaseconnection);
    app.route('/lookupcollections').get(query.lookupcollections);
    app.route('/lookupcollection').get(query.lookupcollection);
    app.route('/showhistory').get(query.showhistory);
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Where is your server code?

Comment: That is the server code.  iI's NodeJS.  NodeJS is the server (aka backend).  It's a server and a client together in one big Electron app.

Comment: I know. but if you call listen(3001) and nothing changes, then its not the right part... Where is your real server code?! Whats the content of `backend_routes/query`?

Comment: I updated the question to show that code as well.

Comment: Wha is the backend object? Please  add your **full** code

Comment: I figured out what the problem is -- the configuration is being overwritten by a file outside the directory structure of the app itself, something I'd forgotten about.  So the backend was being served at 3001 and the frontend was making URLs to a different location based on that configuration.  backend.listen(3001) really does make the backend listen on port 3001.